# How to calculate confidence interval in ROC Analysis in R?

Tags: r, roc, auc

I am doing ROC Analysis in R. I want to calculate CI of the AUC. I don't want to use specific packages like pROC or others. How can I calculate confidence interval of AUC in the code below?

In the code below, I have splitted the iris data and I am doing ROC anlaysis by using naive bayes algorithm.
Thanks

```
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")
data(iris)

lvls = levels(iris$Species)

aucs = c()

testidx = which(1:length(iris[, 1]) %% 5 == 0) 
iris.train = iris[testidx, ]
iris.test = iris[-testidx, ]


acc_need<-  c("Sensitivity", "Specificity", "PPV", "NPV", "AUC")
all_res <- matrix(NA, nrow = (1), ncol=length(acc_need))
colnames(all_res)<-acc_need
rownames(all_res)<-c("row1")
all_res

data1<-iris.train
type.id<-1
data1$Dependent    =  as.factor(data1$Species == lvls[type.id])
mytarget <- "Dependent"
myFormula <- as.formula(paste(paste(mytarget,"~"), "Sepal.Length"))
myFormula

nbmodel       =  NaiveBayes(myFormula, data=data1)
 
resp<-which(colnames(data1)=="Dependent")

nbprediction  =  predict(nbmodel, newdata = iris.test[,c("Sepal.Length", "Species")], type='raw')

score = nbprediction$posterior[, 'TRUE']
actual.class = iris.test$Species == lvls[type.id]
pred   = prediction(score, actual.class)





nbauc = performance(pred, "auc")
nbauc = unlist(slot(nbauc, "y.values"))
aucs[type.id] = nbauc

pred   = prediction(score, actual.class)


#AUC
nbauc = performance(pred, "auc")
nbauc = unlist(slot(nbauc, "y.values"))
aucs[type.id] = nbauc

#Sens 
nbsens = performance(pred, "sens")
nbsens = unlist(slot(nbsens, "y.values"))

#Spec
nbspec = performance(pred, "spec")
nbspec = unlist(slot(nbspec, "y.values"))

#PPV
nbppv = performance(pred, "ppv")
nbppv = unlist(slot(nbppv, "y.values"))

#nPVx
nbnpv = performance(pred, "npv")
nbnpv = unlist(slot(nbnpv, "y.values"))

# G-means  
th<-which.max(sqrt(nbsens*nbspec))


# "Sensitivity","Specificity","PPV","NPV","AUC"

all_res[type.id,]<-round(c(nbsens[th], nbspec[th], nbppv[th],nbnpv[th], nbauc),4)
all_res<-all_res[1,]
all_res
```

Comment: This is not a trivial calculation. Typically one uses [DeLong's method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2531595) or bootstrapping, both of which are implemented in the pROC package (partially in C++ code for the DeLong method). Can I ask why you can't use `pROC`? Is this for an assignment? If so, that's a pretty tough assignment!

Comment: You're using ROCR and several other packages.... Why not pROC?

Comment: An very basic approach is to first estimate the variance $\sigma_{JK}$ of AUC with the [jackknife method](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-9/issue-3/The-Jackknife-Estimate-of-Variance/10.1214/aos/1176345462.full), and then approximate the confidence interval as $\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\cdot\sigma_{JK}$. This assumes that the AUC is normally distributed, but it is nevertheless a rough estimate.